# Drupal theme does not change when it is modified

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am creating a drupal theme and use role theme switcher to change the theme according to user role
for the the role anonymous I've created a custom theme
the theme html script does not change whatever the changes I make
I've cleared the cache from performance

Comment: Did you also clear the client side cache?

Comment: yes I cleared the client side cache and this problem on any device I did not open website on it before

Comment: You need to clear Druapls cache. https://www.drupal.org/node/337176

Answer (score 0):

remove the cache from administrator->performance clear cache
change the default theme to new and fresh theme ( I am using zen) and run  module and its custom theme 
it may need modification in css or js files

Answer (score 0):

Heed Drupal's unofficial moto when developing a theme:

[image]

Also, there are many base themes ([Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) for instance) which have a setting to clear the cache on every page request during theme development. You turn this off once the theme is completed, but it's a nice feature when you're still working on things to avoid caching issues.